# Heroku - Permission denied?

Tags: ubuntu, heroku

When I try to restore a backup I get the following error: Permission denied - /var/www/.netrc

I would like to know how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

> ```
> Error:       Permission denied - /var/www/.netrc (Errno::EACCES)
> Backtrace:   /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/netrc-0.7.7/lib/netrc.rb:37:in `read'
>              /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/netrc-0.7.7/lib/netrc.rb:37:in `read'
>              /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:119:in `netrc'
>              /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:143:in `read_credentials'
>              /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:84:in `get_credentials'
>              /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:74:in `password'
>              /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:17:in `api'
>              /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:40:in `api'
>              /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/pgbackups.rb:204:in `config_vars'
>              /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/pgbackups.rb:208:in`pgbackup_client'
>              /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/pgbackups.rb:53:in `url'
>              /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:206:in `run'
>              /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
>              /usr/bin/heroku:25:in `<main>'
>
> Command:     heroku pgbackups:url -a sony-staging-hannibal-mobovivo
> Version:     heroku-toolbelt/2.36.1 (x86_64-linux) ruby/1.9.2
> ```

**SOLUTION**
Reinstalling the heroku-toolbelt according to instructions at:

https://toolbelt.heroku.com/

solved the issue. Thank you again! :)

Comment: $ whoami returns www-data. And the OS is ubuntu

Comment: is /var/www your home? do you have read/write access to the .netrc file there?

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your client with `$ heroku update`. Current version is 2.37

Answer (score 0):

Try using

sudo heroku login

it worked for me on debian linux